# Atmospheric correction for pansharpened imagery?

Tags: remote-sensing, pansharpening, toa-calibration, maxar-digitalglobe

In converting DN values to radiance as well as reflectance, do we use the same equations in raw satellite imagery for pansharpened products? I saw this DigitalGlobe technical note for DN to radiance conversion where "the information applies to all Quickbird products EXCEPT pansharpened" imagery. So may I know then how pansharpened imagery are atmospherically corrected, i.e from DN to radiance to reflectance?

Comment: Maybe you could rephrase the title. The questions are about converting from DN to Top of Atmosphere Radiance/Reflectance.

Comment: Maybe this paper from DigitalGlobe can help: http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/ielx7/36/6819879/06737293.pdf?tp=&arnumber=6737293&isnumber=6819879

Answer (score 7):

There are multiple things to respond to in your question.

**1.** The title of your question refers to atmospheric correction, while the information you refer to in the text is focused around converting to radiance. These two things should not be confused.

**2.** It does not make physical sense to atmospherically correct pansharpend data using standard methods due to the addition of the panchromatic signal to the multispectral data. However, that doesn't mean that you can't ignore those problems and do it anyway. If you choose to atmospherically correct pansharpend data you should keep in mind that the pansharpening will have changed the DN-values slightly and as such, you will have introduced a small source of errors into your reflectance errors.
All in all, my own experience shows that the errors caused by atmospherically correcting pansharpend data are minor and if the objects that you are mapping truely require the improved resolution the errors introduced are small enough to justify it.

On a related note, don't forego the chance to compare the results (a) atmospheric correction followed by pansharpening and (b) pansharpening followed by atmospheric correction. This will help you understand which errors your methodology introduces.

If your data is pansharpend by DigitalGlobe, you will need to use the formulas from the User Guide with the variable values from the supplied .IMD-file to convert to TOA Radiance. In this case, you may end up with larger than necessary errors, as you have no control of the pansharpening process. This is one of the reasons why the bundle containing separate multispectral and panchromatic bands should be purchased by technical users, rather than already pansharpend data.
Related to all of this, consider checking with your data distributor if you can acquire atmospherically corrected data from them. DigitalGlobe have recently started offering their own atmospheric correction through some resellers at a slight increase in price.

Comment: Thanks Mikkel. I could not find any guide from DigitalGlobe on how to convert DN values to radiance and then reflectance for my pansharpened imagery which are Ortho-Ready Standard 2A. Funny thing is that the equations appeared to work for the 2006 Quickbird image with a clearer image and a range of positive values but for the 2010 GeoEye-1 and 2014 Worldview-3 imagery, the DN-to-radiance-to-reflectance computations produced negative values. Perhaps a lesson learned to purchase the bundle rather than pansharpened but could there possibly any way to get the reflectance values for the two images?

Comment: @bean, going from DN to radiance is done using the information from the IMD-file combined with the formulas in https://www.digitalglobe.com/sites/default/files/Radiometric_Use_of_WorldView-2_Imagery%20(1).pdfhttps://www.digitalglobe.com/sites/default/files/Radiometric_Use_of_WorldView-2_Imagery%20(1).pdf From radiance to reflectance requires specialized software, such as FLAASH in the ENVI software or an implementation of 6S.

Comment: In this related question thread I posed: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/148876/preprocessing-geoeye-1-in-grass-iatcorr, there is a suggestion that perhaps, my data have already been converted to radiance from DN hence I don't need to do this preprocessing but go directly to atmosheric correction. As I have said, I bought images that were already pansharpened, radiometrically corrected. In this case, do they need to convert the DN to radiance for pansharpening purposes or is this a requirement for ortho-ready products?

Comment: What are your minimum and maximum values, @bean ?

Comment: Mikkel, band 1-4 (Quickbird: 0-1430; 0-1863; 0-1463; 0-1879) (GeoEye-1: all bands 0-2047) (Worldview-3: 0-1861; 0-2047; 0-1901; 0-2047). I guess these are DN then since radiance or reflectance are supposed to range from 0-1?

Comment: Based on those values, what you have is digital numbers. top-of-atmosphere band-integrated radiance image pixels are achieved by multiplying by 'absCalFactor' and dividing by 'effectiveBandwidth', both of which can be found in the IMD-file delivered with the data. Remember that each band in each acquisition have its own set of values and they should not be reused. With this, you should get radiance values that are above 5 and below 500 (roughly). Remember that radiance is a physical size with a unit and not a percentage. Furthermore, different software packages result in different units.

Comment: I computed for the radiance with raster calculator using the formula you gave and except for Quickbird imagery which had values ranging from 0 and up, the other two images were indeed above 5 and below 500 as you stated. What may have gone wrong with the Quickbird data or is this normal for this sensor? Another thing is that I don't have access to commercial software and while GRASS is an option, it does not have the required information on sensor and band for GeoEye-1 and Worldview-3 to be used on its i.atcorr 6S algorithm..

Comment: The Quickbird may still be right. That is difficult for me to say given the current amount of information. As for atmospheric correction, 6S is available for you to use, but it is a lot of work to implement for these VHR sensors. You'll have to find the missing data, such as detailed band information.

Comment: @MikkelLydholmRasmussen What about, in case of landsat 8,  if I DOS correct pan band and FLAASH correct other 7 Multispectral bands then finally pansharpen them? I am saying so since I can not FLAASH correct the pan band in envi.

Comment: @SIslam - I don't think that the DOS correction would do anything useful in that case. Just pansharpen with the uncorrected band.

Answer (score 0):

you can perform atmospheric corrections on the MS and PAN bands, then execute pansharpening. It will yield better results that way

Comment: Corse, the problem is I bought images that have already been pansharpened by an authorized reseller. Do you think the images have already been converted to radiance in this process? The DigitalGlobe data are Ortho-Ready Standard 2A.

Comment: usually products are corrected to reflectance instead of radiance values. Then again, couldn't you drop them an email with that very question? I'm sure they would be more than willing to clarify

Answer (score -1):

becous of changing pixels location and values in registering process, you cant perform any radiometric correction, same as radiometric correction. in first level of image correction, you should perform radiometric correction and then geometric correction.

Comment: Pansharpening has nothing to do with geometric correction as long as the panchromatic data comes from the same source, which is true for most cases including this one.